# INT 13h - Extended Read - DAPS fault

Tags: assembly, bootloader

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I wrote some assembly code which is ultimatly supposed to read the root directory. The problem however is that the Extended Read function doesn't place the readed data on the correct location. Or there is something wrong with my segment and offsets.

**The Result I get out of this code is: A| |, Which means the Print Function found a 0, while expecting some random values of the first sector.**

I really don't know what I've done wrong anymore

**BIOS_ReadFile.inc**

```
;*************************************************
;   Name: BIOS_ReadFile.inc
;   Description: Reads File from the FAT32 System
;*************************************************
[bits 16]

%ifndef BIOS_READFILE.INC
%define BIOS_READFILE.INC

%include "Constants.inc"

;-----------------------------------------------------------------  
; BIOS_ReadSectors function
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
ReadStatus: db UNKNOWN              ; 0 - Not Supported, 1 - Supported,     255 - Not known at given time

BIOS_ReadSectors:
mov si, DAPS                    ; Load DAPS Struct to DS:SI
mov ah, 0x42                    ; Read Functions
int 0x13                        ; Call the interrupt
jc .Failure                     ; If the read fails.
mov byte [ReadStatus], TRUE     ; Set the ReadStatus to True
ret                             ; Return

.Failure:
mov byte [ReadStatus], FALSE    ; Set the ReadStatus to False

mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Letter B, Gives Indication of Failure
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
mov al, 'B'
int 0x10

ret 
; Return

;-----------------------------------------------------------------  
; BIOS_ReadFile function
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
FirstDataSector:     dw 0x0
RootDirectorySector: dw 0x0

BIOS_ReadFile:
; Calculating the First Data Sector
xor ax, ax
mov byte al, [Bios_Parameter_Block.FATS]
mul word [Extended_Bios_Parameter_Block.LargeSectorsPerFAT]
add word ax, [Bios_Parameter_Block.ReservedSectors]
mov word [FirstDataSector], ax

; Calculating the Root Directory Sector
mov word ax, [Extended_Bios_Parameter_Block.RootDirectory]
sub word ax, 2
mul byte [Bios_Parameter_Block.SectorsPerCluster]
add word ax, [FirstDataSector]
mov word [RootDirectorySector], ax

; Load Directory
;mov word [DAPS.SectorsToRead], 1

;mov word ax, [RootDirectorySector]
;mov word [DAPS.SectorStart], ax

call BIOS_ReadSectors

mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Letter A, Gives Indication of Failure
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
mov al, 'A'
int 0x10

ret

;-----------------------------------------------------------------  
; Memory Data Structures and Other Variables
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
; Disk Address Packet Structure (Used For Loading Rest of OS)
DAPS:            db 0x10               ; Size of Structure (16 bytes)
                 db 0                  ; Always 0
.SectorsToRead   dw 1                  ; Number of Sectors to Read (1x512)
.Offset          dw 0x7E00             ; Offset to load to.
.Segment         dw 0x0000             ; Segment to load to.
.SectorStart     dq 0                  ; Read from Second Block


;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%endif
```

**Bootloader.asm**

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x0]

jmp Start

%include "BIOS_Parameter_Block.inc"
%include "BIOS_Extensions.inc"
%include "BIOS_ReadFile.inc"
%include "Print.inc"

; Prepare stack segment
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
Start:
cli
mov ax, 0x07C0
mov ds, ax                  ; Load segments with 0
mov fs, ax
mov es, ax
mov gs, ax

mov     ax, 0x0000              ; set the stack
mov     ss, ax
mov     sp, 0xFFFF
mov     bp, 0xFFFF
sti

; Check support for extensions
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
call CheckExtensions
cmp byte [ExtensionsSupported], FALSE
jz short unsupported

; Read from the device.
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
call BIOS_ReadFile

mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Letter B, Gives Indication of Failure
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
mov al, '|'
int 0x10

mov si, 0x200
call PrintString

mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Letter B, Gives Indication of Failure
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
mov al, '|'
int 0x10

cli
hlt

jmp 0x0:0x7E00                  ; Jump to main

; Errors 
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
unsupported:
mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Letter F, Gives Indication of Failure
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
mov al, 'F'
int 0x10

clc
hlt 

; Fill Out Rest of Bootloader
;-----------------------------------------------------------------
times 510-($-$$) db 0

db 0x55, 0xAA               ; Add Boot Record Signature
```

**Print.inc**

```
;*************************************************
;   Name: Print.inc
;   Description: Printing on console using INT 10h
;   Function: PrintString(DS::SI nullTerminatedString)
;*************************************************
[bits 16]

%ifndef PRINT.INC
%define PRINT.INC

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PrintString: 
lodsb               ; Load next byte from DI::SI to AL and increment SI by one
or  al, al          ; Null-Terminator check
jz  .Done           ; If found jump to end
mov ah, 0Eh         ; Move Function number in AH
int 10h             ; Else print character
jmp PrintString     ; Repeat until null terminator found

.Done:
mov ah, 0x0E                ; Print Letter B, Gives Indication of Failure
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
int 0x10

ret                 ; Return
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

%endif

Comment: The segment and offset in `DAPS` don't match the segment and offset in the rest of your bootsector. Refer to the same memory, so I don't think that's your problem (you get back to segment 0 with the final jump, anyway) - but that's all that jumps out at me...

Comment: Eventually it turned out I had to put "mov dl, 0x80" before the read function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually it turned out I had to put "mov dl, 0x80" before the read function.
Still I don't really know why since at the start of the booting process the DL should have the correct drive number according to most specifications.

Comment: `dl` is indeed set to the correct value when bootloader starts. However, before `int 0x13` you are using `mul` instruction which stores result in `dx:ax` overwriting the value BIOS put there.